# Dynamically creating Issue Object depending up on the project To create issue

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-core-webapi, jira-rest-api

I am developing the Web API which calls  jira rest api to creates Issue,subtasks etc. In our company's jira domain there are around 200 projects. Each Project is configured with different default screens. So i had created one issue object and passed the Json object as below to create issue in jira. It works for the MFS Project.

```
    {
"fields": {
    "project": {
        "key": "MFS"
    },
    "summary": "Test Jira Integration API --Testing New XtremeJira Interface",
    "description": "DonTest Jira Integration API ",
    "issuetype": {
        "name": "Defect"
    },
    "fixVersions": [{
        "name": "MFS 15.1.0"
    }, {
        "name": "MFS 15.6.2"
    }],
    "customfield_10182": "1002",
    "priority": {
        "name": "Major",
        "id": "3"
    },
    "versions": [{
        "name": "MFS 15.1.0"
    }, {
        "name": "MFS 15.6.2"
    }],
    "assignee": {
        "name": "kartik"
    },
    "components": [],
    "environment": ""
}}
```

But for other project i am getting error message like

```
{
 "errorMessages ": [],
 "errors ": {
 "customfield_10182": "Field 'customfield_10182' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown. ",
 "environment": "Field 'environment' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown. "
 }
}
```

So i want to handle this issue across all the project with single Issue object that should generate dynamically depending up on eact project fields for creating issue.

Creating the issue object for each project  (like if there are 200 projects in our jira domain -creating issue class with fields of each project ) is not good design .

Can Any One please help me on this. I am developing this in .Net Web Api(c# language)

Answer (score 0):

Actions don't support polymorphism. In other words, there's no way to have a particular derived class be instantiated instead of a base class simply based on what's posted. What you bind to is what you get, so you'll need to bind to a model that accepts every possible value of an "issue", not matter what the exact type.

However, *from there*, you can independently check for the presence of certain values and map to a more specific issue type class. It sounds as if the limiting factor here is the JIRA API. It wants a particularly formatted request body, so you're going to have to map your posted data onto a class that can be serialized into what JIRA wants. Simple as that.